# Simple dot output for Boost Graph edges labelled with basic types

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

Using bundled properties with the Boost Graph Library means it's very simple to create code to output a dot file compatible with graphviz:

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct Edge { int i; };

int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, Edge> Graph;
  Graph g;
  add_edge(0, 1, {123}, g);
  write_graphviz(std::cout, g, default_writer(),
                   make_label_writer(boost::get(&Edge::i,g)));
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above the edge property is defined using a struct called `Edge`. This struct contains only a single `int`; `boost::get` then provides `make_label_writer` with the necessary `PropertyWriter`.

If I would instead like to use a basic type, such as `int` or `double`, for the edge property instead, what are the arguments I now need to pass to `make_label_writer`? Can the code remain comparable to that above. For example, the `adjacency_list` could be declared as:

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, int> Graph;
```

Comment: the code shouldn't compile as `edge` is ambiguous. Fixed your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd address the edge bundle directly.

> With bundled properties, the *pointer-to-member* property tag is implicitly applied to the value of the `edge_bundle_t` property (or `vertex_bundle_t` or `graph_bundle_t` as the case may be; Therefore you wouldn't want to use the same user-defined type for edge/vertex/graph bundles).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/452aa012447f63da)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, int> Graph;
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, 123, g);
    write_graphviz(std::cout, g, default_writer(), 
            make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle,g)));
}
```

Output:

```
digraph G {
0;
1;
0->1 [label=123];
}
```

Comment: Excellent. It's hard to Google edge_bundle when you don't know it's name :)